# Spring MVC: How to treat html suffix like any RequestMapping

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller

I have a legacy system and some url rewrite rule that we want to get rid. One of which is a rule to change is /tools/lookup.html?what=this and change it to /tools/search?what=this and actually returns json and not html !

I'm trying to find a way to have a @Controller to support the legacy format lookup.html, but it fails with HTTP 406 "The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.". I'm wondering if anyone as done something similar?

My controller methods looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tools/lookup.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Result lookup() {
    return result;
}
```

Thanks in advance
Sylvain

Answer (score 1):

Removing the reponsebody annotation will stop the controlle method returning json.

Comment: Hi, I actually want to return json, my problem is that the legacy url use a .html but act as a Rest service. Yes you are right removing the response body annotation would prevent returning json.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at `@RequestMapping`, which supports a `produces` element. E.g.,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tools/search", produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Result search(...) { ... }
```

Comment: Hi Willie, thanks for the answer but no luck. The produces narrow the mapping but doesn't solve my problem (same result). I need to tell Spring to ignore normal .html processing and act as a normal rest method. If I replace .html by .toto it works but I cannot change my legacy URL.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from how spring is treating pathvariables. The default behavior will cut off the last dot in a url (.html) to find the request mappings. 
This effect happens only for the last pathvariable.

I havent found a property yet to change this globally but one way is to tell your pathvariable mapping to use the regex {pathvariable:.+}.

```
@Requestmapping("/somepath/{varwithextention:.+}")
    public String method(@Pathvariable String varwithextension) {
    ...
}
```

Edit: i see that you do not even use pathvars. Probably its still the same effect for the last url part though?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the suggestion, the problems seems to be related with the interaction of the ResponseBody if I return void the proper method is called but I really would like to be able to use the ResponseBody

Comment: Hi, I traced to AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor and it seems that because it ends with .html it forces the only supported type to text/html even when client support application/json. I tried setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false) and setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(false) but reading the doc this doesn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi finally found something that should work in my case, note that my app doesn't need to support real html (REST only app), so this shouldn't have to much side effects. In my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter I added the following media type for html.

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.mediaType("html",MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    configurer.mediaType("html",MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    super.configureContentNegotiation(configurer);
}
```

I now I get my JSON or XML content back in the client. No more 406 error.